# Javascript - How to create a cascading drop-down list of country & cities with one country selected as default in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I want to create a Country-city cascading drop down , when the country will be selected the cities of that specific country will be shown in the 2nd drop-down.

One country will come as default in the 1st or country drop-down , let USA be the default country.

Again one state will be the default of the 2nd drop-down - say New York for USA, London for UK, Moscow for Russia, Madrid for Spain & Delhi for India.

The following is my JSON data.

```
[{
            "id": "1", "name":"USA",
                "cities": [{
                "id": "1",
                    "name": "New York"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                    "name": "Los Angeles"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": "2", "name":"UK",
                "cities": [{
                "id": "3",
                    "name": "London"
            }, {
                "id": "4",
                    "name": "Glasgow"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "3", "name":"Russia",
                "cities": [{
                "id": "5",
                    "name": "Moscow"
            }, {
                "id": "6",
                    "name": "St. Petersburg"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "4", "name":"Spain",
                "cities": [{
                "id": "7",
                    "name": "Madrid"
            }, {
                "id": "8",
                    "name": "Barcelona"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": "5", "name":"India",
                "cities": [{
                "id": "9",
                    "name": "Delhi"
            }, {
                "id": "10",
                    "name": "Mumbai"
            }]
        }]
```

I tried doing this but failed to keep the default country & have a default city for every country.

**I am using Angular v1 & vanilla JS (no JQuery). I do not want to use angular.forEach**

**I am unable to implement the default Country in the 1st drop-down & default City for that particular country in the 2nd drop-down**

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service. Show your attempts so others can help you fix **your code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a way how you can achieve this by using `data-ng-options` (`ng-options`):

Hope this helps.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("app", []);
  app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Demo";
    $scope.data = [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "USA",
      "cities": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "New York"
      }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Los Angeles"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "UK",
      "cities": [{
        "id": "3",
        "name": "London"
      }, {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Glasgow"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Russia",
      "cities": [{
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Moscow"
      }, {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "St. Petersburg"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Spain",
      "cities": [{
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Madrid"
      }, {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Barcelona"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "India",
      "cities": [{
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Delhi"
      }, {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Mumbai"
      }]
    }];
    $scope.country = $scope.data[0]; // Let USA be the default country.
    $scope.city = $scope.country.cities[0]; // Show the first city of USA by default.

    $scope.setCities = function(country) {
      $scope.city = country.cities[0];
    };
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <h3 data-ng-bind="title"></h3>
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select data-ng-model="country" data-ng-change="setCities(country)" data-ng-options="c as c.name for c in data">

    </select>
    <label>Cities:</label>
    <select data-ng-model="city" data-ng-options="ci as ci.name for ci in country.cities">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't know why it is working perfectly in the web view of Chrome Developer but whenever i am choosing mobile view in Chrome ( the devices like Iphone6,Nexus6 etc ) the dropdown is not working

Comment: Works well for me by testing in Google Chrome mobile view Iphone 6, Nexus 6. Please make sure that you're using the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript code. Just for your reference, in case you really can't figure it out. But next time let us know what at least you have tried.

```
<select id="ddlCountries" onchange="onChange()"></select>
<select id="ddlCities"></select>

<script>
    var ddlCountries = document.getElementById("ddlCountries");
    var ddlCities = document.getElementById("ddlCities");
    var data = []; // your json array
    var defaultCountry = data[0];
    loadAllCountries();
    loadDefaultCities();

    function loadAllCountries() {
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var currentCountry = data[i];
                addCountry(currentCountry);
            }
        }
        function loadDefaultCities() {
            addCities(defaultCountry.cities, defaultCountry);
        }
        function addCountry(currentCountry) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = currentCountry.name;
            option.value = currentCountry.id;
            ddlCountries.appendChild(option);
        }
        function addCities(cities, currentCountry) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = cities[i].name;
                option.value = cities[i].id;
                ddlCities.appendChild(option);
                ddlCities.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        function onChange() {
            var selectedCountry = data.find(findById);
            clearDropdownlist(ddlCities);
            addCities(selectedCountry.cities, selectedCountry);
        }
        function findById(country) {
            return country.id == ddlCountries.value;
        }
        function clearDropdownlist(ddl) {
            while (ddl.firstChild) {
                ddl.removeChild(ddl.firstChild);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: can you please help me in Angular?